# Error with configuring update for moodle

Tags: php, moodle

Hey guys I was on an older version of moodle and I...

```
1. removed old files inside dir
2. put in new files
3. copied old config.php file over
```

But I am still getting an error if you go to http://www.clearpathadvantage.com/themoodle you can see it.  I did try and turn of register_global = off because it told me to, but no success so I returned it to normal.

Here is my config file dir and data:

```
$CFG->dirroot   = 'ipdage stuff/site/themoodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'ipdage stuff/site/themoodle/moodledata';
```

One thing also is that the dataroot, with the new files transferred over, there never was a moodledata?

Let me know if you could help :)

David

Comment: register_globals should **NEVER** be on. next to magic_quotes it's one of the greatest stupidities ever foisted upon the programming world.

Comment: Now I am no longer a fool thanks :)

Comment: So any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As i can see that your dirroot and dataroot path is not correct so please follow the [moodle documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Configuration_file) as below -

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://www.mymoodle.com/moodle';
$CFG->dirroot   = '/var/www/moodle'; //should be full path 
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/moodledata'; //should be full path 
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 00777;
```